# How to minimise code and avoid repetition?

Tags: php

I am learning PHP.

I want to calculate number of absent students in a class in all subjects in an examination.

I have used the following code to extract the data for one class and 2 subjects.

I want to calculate number of absent students for four classes and 27 subjects  How to achieve that by using minimum code and avoiding repetition?

```
<?php


/*Query to calculate number of absent students in FYBA in all 6 subjects.  

by counting studid (student id)  

Economics = marks1e*/


$e = mysql_query('select count(studid) from examdbf1 where exam_id =   14153 and faculty = 1 and sem = 1 and repeater = 1 and marks1e = \'AA\'');

$ea = mysql_fetch_array($e);

echo '<br>'. $ea['count(studid)'] . '<br>';


/*Marathi Optional = marks2e*/


$mo = mysql_query('select count(studid) from examdbf1 where exam_id = 14153 and faculty = 1 and sem = 1 and repeater = 1 and marks2e = \'AA\'');

$moa = mysql_fetch_array($mo);

echo '<br>'. $moa['count(studid)'] . '<br>';
```

Comment: use mysqli_ instead of mysql_  Read http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php

Comment: (1) find your repeatable vs changing data, (2) put your changing data in an array, (3) put your repeatable data in a loop, ie. *for()*, *foreach()*, *while()*, or function, with placeholders for your changeable data, (4) run your loop/function using your array(s), (5) update database library from *mysql_* to *mysqli* or *PDO*

Comment: @Sean Created array and loop as you suggested.  Can't understand how to add placeholders for changeable data. `$m = array("marks1e", "marks2e", "marks3e", "marks4e", "marks5e", "marks6e");

$mcount = count($m);`  for loop `for ($x = 0; $x < $mcount; $x++) {

$e = mysql_query('select count(studid) from examdbf1 where exam_id = 14153 and faculty = 1 and sem = 1 and repeater = 1 and ***marks1e*** = \'AA\'');

$ea = mysql_fetch_array($e);

echo '<br>'. $ea['count(studid)'] . '<br>';`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the code from your comment, change your `***marks1e***` to `$m[$x]` -

```
$m = array("marks1e", "marks2e", "marks3e", "marks4e", "marks5e", "marks6e"); 
$mcount = count($m); 
for($x = 0; $x < $mcount; $x++) { 
    $e = mysql_query('SELECT count(studid) FROM examdbf1 WHERE exam_id = 14153 AND faculty = 1 AND sem = 1 AND repeater = 1 AND '.$m[$x].' = \'AA\''); 
    $ea = mysql_fetch_array($e); 
    echo '<br>'.$m[$x].': '. $ea['count(studid)'] . '<br>';
}
```

similarly, since you are only changing the value from `$m`, you could do a `foreach()` -

```
$m = array("marks1e", "marks2e", "marks3e", "marks4e", "marks5e", "marks6e"); 
foreach($m as $n) { 
    $e = mysql_query('SELECT count(studid) FROM examdbf1 WHERE exam_id = 14153 AND faculty = 1 AND sem = 1 AND repeater = 1 AND '.$n.' = \'AA\''); 
    $ea = mysql_fetch_array($e); 
    echo '<br>'.$n.': '. $ea['count(studid)'] . '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Your code is working perfectly.  Your suggestion reduced my code to just 12 lines.   Earlier it was 60 lines.  I want your suggestions to further improve the code.    Each exam is for two semesters and two faculties and there are regular and repeater students appearing for the exam.  Each semester has different number of subjects e.g. 6,7 or 8.   How to modify the above code so that absent report can be displayed for two semesters and two faculties together.  Whether nesting for loop is the way, please give a  hint.